Unable to list keys for azure function app while performing test & deploy
I have an azure function app in S1 app service standard plan. The function app is hosted on a windows app service plan and uses the user assigned managed identity of the function app to connect to its storage account. I've ensured the storage account has 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' and 'Storage Queue Data Contributor' role membership on the storage account. I have an variable named AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName in environment variables with value has name of the storage account.
After doing the deployment I am not able to view the function app keys, it just keeps loading and then gives error "Error while loading system keys, encountered an error (Internal Server Error from host runtime)". Also I am not able to view azure-webjobs-secrets in storage account container. Also I have changed function app code to make use of managed identity instead of using access keys.
Can anyone please help me with the solution, or is there something that I am missing?

Check if below solution helps @SaurabhAgarwal.


Error while loading system keys, encountered an error (Internal Server Error from host runtime)

To resolve this error, add below application settings in the Function App=>Environment variables:

AzureWebJobsStorage__credential: managedidentity

AzureWebJobsStorage__clientId: clientid(can be retrieved from your user managed idenitity)



Application Settings:

I have configured Azure function app with Storage Account using User-defined Managed identity.

Able to access the App Keys:




can confirm that this resolves also the issue in case you are using a flexible consumption plan.
